# Is there any way to add class path to property file?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I am trying to write a property file and wanted to add one classpath resources.

Is there any way to add class path to property file?

Example :

I am creating example1.properties using java properties which are having Following Properties

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

I have another properties file say example2.properties having Following values

```
key3 = value3
```

When i am storing example1.properties file then i need to include example2.propertis file.

**Note : I don't want to include value instead i want to include path to resource example2.properties.**

Actual Output I need is :

**example1.properties**

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
[classpath :/example2.properties]
```

Comment: where you want to include. What is your input and what out you are expecting.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I want to include example2.properties file in **example1.properties**  and this file i am creating using java

Comment: So you need to merge he contents of example1.properties and example2.properties into example1.properties? Please post your code whatever you have done so far.